# Bizarre SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED failure when using javascript CanvasRenderingContext2d

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html5-canvas, out-of-memory

I've been fiddling around with the CanvasRenderingContext2D javascript interface and I keep running into SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED errors in which the browser window crashes.

I've worked to isolate the problem and cut it down to a minimal example. But now I've got two versions, one that works, and one that doesn't, and so far as I can tell they should behave exactly the same. It seems to have something to do with certain CanvasRenderingContext2D calls happening inside for loops. Even when those for-loops are explicitly set to run only once.

The html is just a blank canvas:
`<canvas id="mainCanvas" height=400 width = 400></canvas>`

And then I've got the javascript:

```
//basic setup:
var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//this works fine:
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    ctx.moveTo( 200,200 );
        ctx.lineTo(210,210);
    ctx.stroke()
}

//this crashes
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    ctx.moveTo( 200,200 );
    for(i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        ctx.lineTo(210,210);
    }
    ctx.stroke()
}
```

Those two for loops should behave identically, but the 2nd one throws a SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED error and crashes the chrome window.

What the heck is going on? What am I doing wrong? Is there some rule about having too many for loops nested?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    ctx.moveTo( 200,200 );
    for(i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        ctx.lineTo(210,210);
    }
    ctx.stroke()
}
```

Running a for loop within a for loop using the same variable "i" is not the best idea as you change i to 0 on the second loop again. As the second loop ends when i reaches 1 you will end up in an infinite loop.

The second loop makes abesolutely no sense at all as you set the stop condition to "i < 1". You are running the loop only on time. Why using a loop then?

Comment: Ack. Thats the problem. Wow. How embarrassing.

Comment: No need to be embarrassed, you are here to learn. Just like me. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The inner for-loop changes the value of i, used by the outer for-loop, which in your case creates an infinite loop. Rename one of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem as pointed out by @coldgas and @kaveh was the reuse of the "i" variable. This happened when I stripped down the problem, collapsing functions and stripping away code that doesn't relate to the bug.

The *original* problem that I had was something closer to this (still stripped down a bit, but you get the idea):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

drawCurve = function(x,y,offset=200){
    ctx.moveTo( x[0]+offset,400-y[0]-offset);
    for(i =1; i<x.length;i++){
        ctx.lineTo(x[i]+offset, 400-y[i]-offset);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}
drawX = function(x,y,d,offset=200){
    drawCurve(  [x-d,x+d] ,[y-d,y+d]  )
    drawCurve(  [x-d,x+d] ,[y+d,y-d]  )
}
xylist = [[100,100],[150,150],[0,0],[50,50]]

//this gets stuck in an infinite loop, because drawX calls drawCurve, and drawCurve sets i
for(i = 0; i < xylist.length; i++){
    console.log("hi "+i);
    drawX( xylist[i][0],xylist[i][1], 10 )
    console.log("bye "+i);
}
```

But the problem is actually the same: I didn't include "let" in the beginning of each for loop, so the function-call for-loop was using the same variable as the outer for-loop.

So the fix would be:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

drawCurve = function(x,y,offset=200){
    ctx.moveTo( x[0]+offset,400-y[0]-offset);
    for(let i =1; i<x.length;i++){
        ctx.lineTo(x[i]+offset, 400-y[i]-offset);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}
drawX = function(x,y,d,offset=200){
    drawCurve(  [x-d,x+d] ,[y-d,y+d]  )
    drawCurve(  [x-d,x+d] ,[y+d,y-d]  )
}
xylist = [[100,100],[150,150],[0,0],[50,50]]

for(let i = 0; i < xylist.length; i++){
    console.log("hi "+i);
    drawX( xylist[i][0],xylist[i][1], 10 )
    console.log("bye "+i);
}
```

Note that in both for loops I use "let".

I always forget about javascript's unique scoping...